# Change Case CreatedById

Tags: case

I have a user that has left the company, and a few cases he has initiated are sitting in our Product backlog or currently being worked on.

Is there any workaround to change the CreatedById to the user who is inheriting his responsibilities?

Or, is there a way to add the new user to the case so she receives updates?

The only way I could conceive of doing this is creating a workflow rule just for the particular case to alert the new employee, but I don't want to set that kind of messy precedent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change the CreatedById. Can you not just change the Case owner to the new user?

Comment: We use Case Owner as the person who is working on the Case.  The Case Owner is currently the Product Manager, or Product Queue for a bunch of these.  There is Workflow setup to alert the Case Initiator and Case Owner when there are changes or comments to the Case.

Comment: Given your current situation, I would recommend switching the logic to use the Case Owner instead of the Creator. You could also use custom fields for additional notifications, if needed.

Comment: I would highly suggest creating a new field for `Case Initiator` rather than relying on the `Created By` for any of this type of behavior where the data could need to be altered. The creation of the new field and some Execute Anonymous code to populate it on all of the case records would be very trivial and at that point you could alter your workflow rules to utilize the new custom field instead.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to change the CreatedById but you can certainly alter the OwnerId field to the responsible user.