# Set a specific value for Created By field of a custom object's all records in Salesforce

Tags: apex, system-fields

In salesforce I have a requirement that, I need to set the Created By field value of an object's all records to a particular user, irrespective of the user who creates it through UI/Apex. So how can I do that?

Comment: That is pretty much impossible with the standard UI or Apex. For data migration Salesforce can make it an editable field but this will not be over the long term. You can only set the Owner like this.

Comment: This previous question and answer addresses it though for the Case object http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/change-case-createdbyid

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible using Apex code.

1- We need to create a permission set to give the permissin - "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation".

2- Assign this permission set to each and every user who is responsible for creation of the Object's record.

3- Write an insert trigger for the Object.

4- Write apex code to assign the User's Id (whose name you want to see as Created By) to the CreatedById field of the record.

For Example:

String userID= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

CustomObject__c cor = new CustomObject__c ();

cor.CreatedById = userID;

insert cor;

Answer (score 1):

Short answer No this is not possible.

Longer answer - Salesforce can grant this privilege but it would only be on a time limited basis for things like data migration as this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021710/how-to-change-system-fields-in-salesforce) from Stack Exchange states.

This [previous question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/change-case-createdbyid) addresses it though for the Case object

Better to have a custom 'Record Creator' field that you can update via the UI or Apex.